# MongoDB not able to connect to Node JS using env variables (kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes

I have a container based application running node JS and my backend is a mongoDB container.

Basically, what I am planning to do is to run this in kubernetes.

I have deployed this as separate containers on my current environment and it works fine. I have a mongoDB container and a node JS container.

To connect the two I would do

```
docker run -d --link=mongodb:mongodb -e MONGODB_URL='mongodb://mongodb:27017/user' -p 4000:4000 e922a127d049
```

my connection.js runs as below where it would take the MONGODB_URL and pass into the process.env in my node JS container. My connection.js would then extract the MONGODB_URL into the mongoDbUrl as show below.

```
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const mongoDbUrl = process.env.MONGODB_URL;
//console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URL)
let mongodb;

function connect(callback){
    mongoClient.connect(mongoDbUrl, (err, db) => {
        mongodb = db;
        callback();
    });
}
function get(){
    return mongodb;
}

function close(){
    mongodb.close();
}

module.exports = {
    connect,
    get,
    close
};
```

To deploy on k8s, I have written a yaml file for

1) web controller
2) web service
3) mongoDB controller
4) mongoDB service

This is my current mongoDB controller

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: mongo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mongo:latest
        name: mongo
        ports:
        - name: mongo
          containerPort: 27017
          hostPort: 27017
```

my mongoDB service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: mongodb
  name: mongodb
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    name: mongo
```

my web controller

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ReplicationController
metadata:
  labels:
    name: web
  name: web-controller
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    name: web
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: leexha/node_demo:21
        env:
        - name: MONGODB_URL
          value: "mongodb://mongodb:27017/user"
        name: web
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4000
          name: node-server
```

and my web service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: web
  labels:
    name: web
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 4000
      targetPort: 4000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    name: web
```

I was able to deploy all the services and pods on my local kubernetes cluster.

However, when I tried to access the web application over a nodeport, it tells me that there is a connection error to my mongoDB.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of null
    at /app/app.js:24:17
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
```

This is my node JS code for app.js

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
, MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
, PORT = 4000
, instantMongoCrud = require('express-mongo-crud') // require the module
, express = require('express')
, app = express()
, path = require('path')
, options = { //specify options
    host: `localhost:${PORT}`
}
, db = require('./connection')


// connection to database
db.connect(() => {

    app.use(bodyParser.json()); // add body parser
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    //console.log('Hello ' + process.env.MONGODB_URL)

    // get function 
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        db.get().collection('users').find({}).toArray(function(err, data){
            if (err)
                console.log(err)
            else
                res.render('../views/pages/index.ejs',{data:data});
        });
    });
```

Clearly, this is an error when my node JS application is unable to read the mongoDB service.

I at first thought my MONGODB_URL was not set in my container. However, when I checked the nodeJS container using

```
kubectl exec -it web-controller-r269f /bin/bash
```

and echo my MONGODB_URL it returned me back mongodb://mongodb:27017/user which is correct.

Im quite unsure what I am doing wrong as I am pretty sure I have done everything in order and my web deployment is communicating to mongoDB service. Any help? Sorry am still learning kubernetes and please pardon any mistakes

Comment: the error is shown in /app/app.js can you paste its snippet too ?

Comment: app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        db.get().collection('users').find({}).toArray(function(err, data){
            if (err)
                console.log(err)
            else
                res.render('../views/pages/index.ejs',{data:data});
        });
    });

Comment: can you add an err check in your connection.js after mongoClient.connect(mongoDbUrl, (err, db) => { to check error and print error to console.

Comment: Also can you once delete the web-controller pod and start It again? Leave the other pods as it. It could be the issue of the pod starting. Your web-controller might have started first then the mongo one.

Comment: I tried delete webcontroller pod and restart. i wrote a console log but how do i check the logs in the container for this?

Comment: was able to get it tailing the logs:

checking database
Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [mongodb:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.111.154.130:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1054:14) {
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 10.111.154.130:27017'
}]

Comment: my container for my mongoDB container:

mongodb       ClusterIP   10.111.154.130   <none>        27017/TCP        27m

Comment: Hi I ran your given yaml codes on my local cluster and everything worked fine. I didn't. got any port issue. Could be the issue of the ports in your machine, try enabling all and testing it.

Comment: Hi anushul I'm not sure. I'm running this in my local desktop kubernetes 1 master  cluster to test.  is your local cluster deployed on your desktop?

Comment: I deployed in the cloud but it should not be any difference from your local Kubernetes cluster. Try the procedure mentioned by @redgetan.

Comment: Hi anshui, I followed as per what was stated. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt. Is there anything I am missing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit]

Sorry my bad, the connections string `mongodb://mongodb:27017` would actually work. I tried dns querying that name, and it was able to resolve to the correct ip address even without specifying ".default.svc...".

`root@web-controller-mlplb:/app# host mongodb
mongodb.default.svc.cluster.local has address 10.108.119.125`

@Anshul Jindal is correct that you have race condition, where the web pods are being loaded first before the database pods. You were probably doing `kubectl apply -f .` Try doing a reset `kubectl delete -f .` in the folder containing those yaml . Then `kubectl apply` the database manifests first, then after a few seconds, `kubectl apply` the web manifests. You could also probably use Init Containers to check when the mongo service is ready, before running the pods. Or, you can also do that check in your node.js application.

**Example of waiting for mongodb service in Node.js**

In your connection.js file, you can change the connect function such that if it fails the first time (i.e due to mongodb service/pod not being available yet), it will retry again every 3 seconds until a connection can be established. This way, you don't even have to worry about load order of applying kubernetes manifests, you can just `kubectl apply -f .`

```
let RECONNECT_INTERVAL = 3000

function connect(callback){
      mongoClient.connect(mongoDbUrl, (err, db) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("attempting to reconnect to " + mongoDbUrl)
          setTimeout(connect.bind(this, callback), RECONNECT_INTERVAL)
          return
        } else {
          mongodb = db;
          callback();
        }
      });
}
```

Comment: hi Redgetan, unfortunately it didnt work. I deployed to default namespace.

Comment: I actually removed my deplyment web service and my web service web and tried again. 

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    name: web
  name: web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: leexha/node_demo:23
        env:
        - name: MONGODB_URL
          value: "mongodb://mongodb.default.svc.cluster.local:27017/user"
        name: web
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4000
          name: web

Comment: @adr if you do `kubectl get svc`, do you see mongodb in the list? When you ssh into your web pod, does `nslookup kubernetes.default` or `nslookup mongodb.default.svc.cluster.local` work ? Here is another useful link  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-service/ . What does your `kubectl log <pod_name>` show?

Comment: hihi yes i do see mongodb in the list. also I couldnt do nslookup in my pod- says nslookup not found. 

for the logs see the following comment

Comment: Error from server (BadRequest): a container name must be specified for pod web-5b5d7fd596-ctn2q, choose one of: [web istio-proxy] or one of the init containers: [istio-init]
ladrian-a01:mongo-node adrianlee$ kubectl logs web-5b5d7fd596-ctn2q -c web

checking database
{ Error [MongoError]: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.109.232.130:27017]
   'failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.109.232.130:27017]' }

Comment: @adr i've updated my answer. its a race condition thing. I was able to make it work after encountering the same error as you

Comment: so I create -f the mongoDB controller 4) mongoDB service first then create -f the node js apps?

Comment: @adr yes. mongo yaml files first, then the nodejs ones

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it. One thing to add, how would i initialise the mongoDB deployment with certain data inside ?

Comment: Hi, I followed as per what was stated. Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt. Is there anything I am missing out?

Comment: @adr Sometimes it doesnt work because you didnt wait long enough for the mongodb service to available before applying the web manifests.  Anyway, I've updated the answer to include an example of how you can change your nodejs code to wait/retry for mongo connection availability. This would make your life easier